# ReactJs: useEffect is not updating the local variable

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-variables

I am developing a skeleton for an application using the `react.js` with actual scenarios until the APIs are being developed.

The local variable called `accountType` generates a dropdown in the `Form` component, is not getting updated.

If I am console logging inside the `useEffect` function then its working, but the variable is not getting updated.

```js
export default () => {
    let accountTypes: Array<Object> = [];
    ...

    useEffect(() => {
        accountTypes = [
            {
                value: 1,
                label: 'Developer',
            },
            {
                value: 2,
                label: 'Personal',
            },
            {
                value: 3,
                label: 'Professional',
            },
        ];
    }, []);

    console.log(accountTypes);

    return (
        <Form accountTypes={accountTypes}>
           ...
        </Form>
    )
});
```

[image]

Not sure how to handle it as this is my first try on any frontend framework.

Comment: Your component is a function. On every call/render you get a new (local) `let accountTypes: Array<Object> = [];` but your effect only updates the one on the very first call. `useState()` or `useRef()` to keep the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the example how to use useState hook. you can use take the reference from below code.

```js
import React from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [accountTypes, setAccountTypes] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setAccountTypes([
      {
        value: 1,
        label: "Developer"
      },
      {
        value: 2,
        label: "Personal"
      },
      {
        value: 3,
        label: "Professional"
      }
    ]);
  }, []);

  console.log(accountTypes);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work just fine. But in React there is a order in which some things 'execute' like @Thomas mentioned the [`useEffect`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect) only runs once on the first render. Since you have React Strictmode turned on, as it is by default, you see your **console.log** two times. Also every time a component re-renders it creates new local variables.

If you add a **console.log** in the `useEffect` you'll see that the value of `accountTypes` has changed to the expected value.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  accountTypes = [
    {
      value: 1,
      label: "Developer",
    },
    {
      value: 2,
      label: "Personal",
    },
    {
      value: 3,
      label: "Professional",
    },
  ];
  console.log(accountTypes);
}, []);
```

However assigning this new value to the variable does not trigger a re-render. In React we use `useState`. If you want initial values you can directly add them to the `useState` hook like so.

See [State: A Component's Memory](https://react.dev/learn/state-a-components-memory) from the react.dev documentation.

```js
const [accountTypes, setAccountTypes] = useState([
  {
    value: 1,
    label: "Developer",
  },
  {
    value: 2,
    label: "Personal",
  },
  {
    value: 3,
    label: "Professional",
  },
]);
```

Or using the `useEffect` hook

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setAccountTypes([
    {
      value: 1,
      label: "Developer",
    },
    {
      value: 2,
      label: "Personal",
    },
    {
      value: 3,
      label: "Professional",
    },
  ]);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

What's going on here is that on first render, useEffect run, setting your variable, but then on subsequent runs, it gets set back to an empty array. I personally, would set it up like this:

```
const accountTypes = [
            {
                value: 1,
                label: 'Developer',
            },
            {
                value: 2,
                label: 'Personal',
            },
            {
                value: 3,
                label: 'Professional',
            },
        ];

export default function AccountForm() {
   return (
        <Form accountTypes={accountTypes}>
           ...
        </Form>
    );
}
```

However, if you expect to need to edit `accountTypes`, I would set it up like this:

```
export default function AccountForm() {
   const [accountTypes, setAccountTypes] = useState([
        {
            value: 1,
            label: 'Developer',
        },
        {
            value: 2,
            label: 'Personal',
        },
        {
            value: 3,
            label: 'Professional',
        },
    ]);

   return (
        <Form accountTypes={accountTypes}>
           ...
        </Form>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEM :** You are getting [] in accountTypes because the UI is rendered before the UseEffect and since its local variable you can not see updated variable in console.log.

The answer given by [Risheekant Vishwakarma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7995612/risheekant-vishwakarma) is correct.
Here is another approach using [USEREF](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef) to achieve what you want.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export default () => {
  const accountTypesRef = useRef([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    accountTypesRef.current = [
      {
        value: 1,
        label: 'Developer',
      },
      {
        value: 2,
        label: 'Personal',
      },
      {
        value: 3,
        label: 'Professional',
      },
    ];
  }, []);

  console.log(accountTypesRef.current);

  return (
    <Form accountTypes={accountTypesRef.current}>
      {/* ... */}
    </Form>
  );
};
```